# Performance comparison

Tags: sql-server

I have two queries for achieving same result...

```
SET 
  @SalesPersonID = (SELECT SUBSTRING((SELECT DISTINCT ' ,' + CAST(AssignedTo AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) 
                    FROM dbo.CustomerCall 
                    WHERE CompanyID = @Companyid 
                      AND ISNULL(isDeleted, 0) = 0  
                      AND AssignedTo IN (SELECT UserID FROM dbo.users 
                                         WHERE IsActivatedUser = 1) 
                    FOR XML PATH('')), 3, 8000))
```

and

```
SELECT 
   @SalesPersonID = COALESCE(@SalesPersonID + ',', ' ') + ' ' +  CAST(AssignedTo AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) 
FROM 
   dbo.CustomerCall  
WHERE 
   CompanyID = 1660 
   AND ISNULL(isDeleted, 0) = 0  
   AND AssignedTo IN (SELECT UserID FROM dbo.users WHERE IsActivatedUser = 1)
```

Which is better performance wise?

The thing is I used xml method before, my senior said it is very bad performance... I showed him execution plan xml plan was marginally better at 47% but he is not ready to accept that. again argued that now data is less(around 1k rows) so executing quickly, what if data increases(say 100k rows)... So need some clarification on both method...

Answer (score 0):

As a tip for comparing query performance you can write both of them in a new query window in Management Studio, then click on `Include Actual Execution Plan` button, then run them at once, then in the result window go to `Execution Plan` there are sql execution plan, and on top you can see `Query Cost` which should be 50% if the performance is same, but if one of them has fewer cost so it's performance is better.

See picture below

[image]

Answer (score 0):

First of all, these are two different queries working on different tables, so can't be compared side by side.

If you were interested in difference between the two approaches to string concatenation, always use the first on (utilizing `FOR XML PATH`), not only for performance reason - it is supported, order is guaranteed..